# uiautomatorviewer.bat opens command prompt and closes. Never opens application

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation

i am trying to start the uiautomatorviewer.bat for the Android SDK. When I click the .bat file, the command prompt opens and I see a command being put into it, then it just closes and the application never opens. I was able to get a very quick screenshot before it closed with the errors:

[Command prompt with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9jkg.png)

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded from java 9 to java 8 and it fixed.